# Why get control sequences expanded in the process of writing them to an auxiliary file?

Tags: write

I was looking at LamsTeX, an old TeX format, because it has some interesting macros.  I found this [article](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan//digests/texline/no13/lamstex) about it.  In the article we can read

> \bitem Many \LaTeX\ difficulties just now being addressed have simply never existed
>   in \LamSTeX{}. For example, there are no such things as `fragile' commands in
>   \LamSTeX{}, and no worries about long |\write|'s and undesired expansions in
>   |\write|'s to auxiliary files (like the |.toc| file). Arbitrarily long literal
>   mode material can split across pages.

So I got interested and made some experiments with LamsTeX.  Looking at the `.toc` auto-generated file I found that LamsTeX saves all control sequences without expansion, like if they were all "protected" using LaTeX or OPmac terminology.  This brought me up a question:  what's the need of expanding a control sequence before writing it?  Wouldn't it be better to simply write it without expansion?

I have looked at other questions related to this argument, but I can't find the answer to this question.

Comment: One reason may be that writing control sequences to the `.aux` files may occur to the time when the sequence is defined in the document body (speaking of `LaTeX` right now), but this command is not available then at the time when the auxiliary files is read

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, that's a good reason!

Comment: also many commands need to be expanded to work, pagenumbers written to the aux file for cross references would not work if they were all written as `\thepage` but in general it is true that making things not expand would probably be the default if etex or more memory had been available in 1980s

Comment: @DavidCarlisle More memory for what, for storing control sequences?

Comment: etex `\protected` attaches an extra flag to each control sequence that determines whether it expands in a write, however the clasic latex \protect mechanism makes a command robust via defining `\def\foo{\protect\internalfoo}`, `\def\internalfoo{real stuff}` so making all commands robust  would double the number of csnames used. when latex2e launched in 93 then latex+amsmath left around 50 csnames free in emtex, so using twice as many csnames in the format wasn't an option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "So making all commands robust would double the number of csnames used."  Can't all commands be assumed robust without attaching them the `\protect` control sequence?  I mean, it is enough to define the LaTeX writing mechanism so that it does not expand any control sequence (if not necessary).

Comment: possibly (using tokens registers) but asking what might have been in Leslie Lamports head last century in an alternate universe is hard to answer:-)

Comment: leslie lamport and michael spivak obviously had very different ideas of how to do things.  i haven't looked at lamstex for a long time, but it *did* implement referencing that wasn't included in amstex, apparently in a much different way than did latex, and it didn't have any more memory to work with.  so that's not a good argument.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is “because Knuth decided this way”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically four fields with information about section when saving to temporary file:

- The control sequence prefixed before all others, executed when the data are read again using `\input`. It must be no expanded during writing process.
- The number of section, chapter etc. It must be expanded immediately.
- The title of the section. It should be no expanded during writing.
- The number of the page. It must be expanded during `\shipout`.

LaTeX manages the third field as: "expand it during `\shipout` but use `\noexpand` expansion of so called robust commands". OPmac does something similar, only control sequences marked as "protected" are set to `\relax` during `\shipout`. But there exists another approach which definitely does not expand the section title during `\shipout`. For example, this can be done like this (classical TeX is expected, no eTeX).

```
\newcount\secnum
\newwrite\outfile
...
\def\meaninga#1{\expandafter\meaningb\meaning#1\relax}
\def\meaningb#1->#2\relax{#2}
\def\sec#1\par{\advance\secnum by1
   \def\tmp{#1}\edef\tmp{\string\secX{\the\secnum}{\meaninga\tmp}}%
   \write\outfile\expandafter{\tmp{\the\pageno}}%
   ...
}
```

First field is `\secX` here protected by `\string`. Second field is `\the\secnum` here expanded during `\edef\tmp`. Third field (section title) is protected using `\meaning` primitive, i.e. it is detokenized immediately when `\edef\tmp` is processed. Fourth field is `\the\pageno` and it is expanded during `\shipout`. Maybe something similar is done in LamsTeX (I don't know exactly).

Of course, if we have eTeX then we can do the detokenization more straightforward using `\detokenize` primitive. And the alternative "protecting" approach can be done more straightforward too: using `\protected\def`.

Note that you cannot use `\the\toks` for expansion protecting of section title because this doesn't do catcode changing and you cannot use `\the\toks` in `\shipout` time because there can be more than one section at one page.